# Atributos em react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Boa tarde, eu estou com um projeto em que tenho que armazenar um dado de um TextInput e validar se ele está vazio ou se tem algum valor.

Eu ja tentei usar setState no input e chamar uma função que valida,
porem pelo que me parece o valor do input não está sendo armazenado (como se o setState não estivesse funcionando).

Estou começando agora com react-native, espero que tenha sido possivel entender minha pergunta.

Agradeço desde já.

````
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: '',
    }
}

<Nome /> ``` Aqui é onde o usuario digita o nome e seria armazenado na propriedade "name: "  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque todo o código possível para nos ajudar a entender melhor o problema. Por favor!

O mais importante para pegar o valor no react é usar o state, porem para setar um valor no state. Você precisa usar o this.setState(valor)

Dá uma olhada no código abaixo e visita esse [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => PizzaTranslator);


  [1]: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input
```